# Salesforce home page issue?

Tags: page-layout, org, lightning-home-page

I have set a home page as a default landing page & done with all the necessary customization, but whenever I logout from the org and then again login into the org, it takes me to the last opened page & not the home page.
Please, can someone tell me the reason behind this?

Comment: Do you have login flows?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal I didn't get your question?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are in the community. You can call this as a bug/feature that salesforce remembers the last page you visited on community and when next time you logged in it redirects you to the same page.

You can raise a case with Salesforce but I don't think it will help you.